# Search by date SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Hello everyone i want search data from invoices and client by today date
I'm using `GETDATE()`

for example two tables

1  Client

```
 - ID   int
 - Name Varcher
```

2 Invoice

```
 - ID int
 - ClientID int
 - date  Datetime
 - Total  money
```

**query**

```
  Select * 
  from client c 
        inner join invoice i on c.id = i.ClientID 
  where i.date = getdate()
```

**result**

```
  nothing
```

but i have some data have same date today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following where condition

```
WHERE DateDiff(dd, OrderDate, getdate()) = 0
or 
WHERE Convert(varchar(20), OrderDate, 101) = Convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 101)
```

so your answer is

```
Select * 
  from client c 
        inner join invoice i on c.id = i.ClientID 
  WHERE DateDiff(dd, i.date, getdate()) = 0
```

Comment: the query is true but why to write equal 0 
the Syntax is DATEDIFF (datepart ,startdate ,enddate )
please answer me

Answer (score 1):

one way

```
where i.date >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0),
and i.date < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())+1 , 0)
```

Comment: I'd deleted my answer anyway and +1ed yours as when I saw yours I realised that I'd not taken into account the possibility of future dates but it works fine. In the execution plan the predicate is `CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,datediff(day,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000',getdate()),0)` which is pretty much what yours is doing I think.

Answer (score 1):

GETDATE() returns both Date and Time.

We need to floor the date to the beginning of today.

```
SELECT * 
FROM client c 
INNER JOIN invoice i 
   ON c.id = i.ClientID 
WHERE i.date >= CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS float)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Just cast into a variable and then do a between:

WHERE i.date BETWEEN @todayDate AND @todayDate+1

Answer (score 0):

Try using DATEPART instead of just getdate() (which will only match dates EXACTLY):

```
WHERE DATEPART(dy, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(dy, i.date) <= 1
```

This will give you all dates in a single day range.

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from client c left join invoice i 
                        on c.id = i.ClientID
   where i.date = getdate()`